# Why my web app behind a firewall returns my ip address instead of domain name?

Tags: php, linux, apache, firewall, moodle

I have been working on a web app which runs ok on my laptop.

It was working fine on office local web servers (accessing via **local ip 172.22.1.1**), but then when they put it behind a firewall and asigned it an **static ip 84.--- with *domain name* mywebsite.com**(dns resolves with the static ip correctly), things went wrong.

For example when I redirect my users back, instead of going to domain name, it returns to the 172.21.1.1.
Then I did `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];` and I saw that it returns the local IP instead of domain name.

Now I don't have any idea what is the problem? Is it something about the firewall setting or it is related to the server setting, virtual hosts or ...

**Moodle:** The same problem goes to moodle too, it was working fine when I assigned the `$CFG->wwwroot` with local ip but when firewall and static ip enabled, then I set it like `$CFG->wwwroot = 'http://mywebsite.com/lms';`, and it gives following error

> "Incorrect access detected, this server may be accessed only through
>   "http://mywebsite.com/lms" address, sorry.

I read about using moodle behind firewall and **masquerading** in moodle documentation but I couldn't figure out how to work it out.

---

**NOTE:**

- This problem goes for both local and external access(after firewall)
- I have not changed any apache or host or other configuration
- The website is in web server's root directory.

Comment: It sounds as something missed in your application configuration (config.php) or a BD value.

Comment: Note that `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is set by the client. Try `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

Comment: @AUsr19532 tried, it gives the same result as the host :/

Comment: Maybe [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername) helps

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Reverse DNS setting right?
Maybe it can't resolve the name and give back the IP.
Try to add the rDNS info, and as AUsr19532 said, try with $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] too.

Comment: if the firewall forwards the WEB port, and there is a DNS service too, Let forwards the UDP/port 53 as well.